# xcode 8.1 xib editing hang, text editor workaround?

Tags: xcode8

So, since updating, the gui randomly hangs editing a xib file. The scenario goes like this:

[image]

1. click an object - i.e, array controller
2. expand a parameter, Filter Predicate here
3. Select target object in pull down
4. try to enter model key path - HANG

In different xib files, the hang comes when trying to enter the model key path textfield.  I've also seen errors citing bogus fields like 'Hidden3' for some attribute bindings - only workaround was to remove them.

Has anyone ventured to editing the xml directly, but I guess I can do that in code :-(

Comment: It almost hung for me, but then after a few seconds i was able to enter the model key path... but it did crash right after hitting undo a few times. Have you reported the behavior to Apple?

Comment: No will do; also notice another anomaly - may object groupings are different, almost random.

Comment: Yeah definitely a bug 

Comment: Same thing here. XCode8.1 hangs while on xib. OS version -> El Capitan

Comment: It's a swag, but I'm going to try to edit using IB from the 3.2.6 kit, using a separate setup of course. Either the new version is finding things broken or it's broke. I hope the latter and editing xibs circa the 3.2 time timeframe might be better served back then in the meanwhile.

Comment: No joy. Using 8.1, I changed format back to xcode 7, tried to open a xib under 7.3.1 but it crashed.  Maybe the xib got more than 'upgraded'? :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I know this is an old question, but I found an answer.
My situation was similar to the one described above: Xcode hanging whenever I edited the key path of any binding in Xcode 8.1.  Nothing described here or elsewhere worked.

However, what did work was to edit the storyboard **outside** of the actual Xcode project: open the offending StoryBoard by itself, do not access it through the project.

This appears consistent with a Sample/Spindump through the Activity Monitor when Xcode hung that showed functions that appeared related to auto-completion/edition. Unchecking auto-completion did not work though (in Prefs).